# How to sum only visible cells on Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets

As per question title, how to sum only the visible cells on Google Spreadsheets?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

I found the solution, which is to use the [`SUBTOTAL`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093649) function with [`109`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FlDyU.png) as its first argument.

Here's an example that will sum only the visible values in the B2:B11 interval:

```
=SUBTOTAL(109,B2:B11)
```

In German and some other languages, you use a semi-colon instead of a comma:

```
=SUBTOTAL(109;B2:B11)
```

Comment: Note that [per the docs](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093649?hl=en), 1) it is a comma that separates cell range from subtotal type, not a semicolon; 2) the prefix "10" is unnecessary, so you could also use `=SUBTOTAL(9, B2:B11)`

Comment: @Oliver In german it is `;` because `,` separates whole numbers from their fractional parts.

Comment: Good to know thx

Comment: Cool! I see at https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093649 that `103` means `COUNTA` with hidden values skipped. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65642280/google-sheet-countif-only-visible-data-using-sumtotal#comment122278921_65644056